# How to pass a JSON object using form data to a rest service using JS

Tags: javascript, html, json, rest

I have a rest webservice which can accept a string. I want to pass a json object as a string to this service. I have to use a HTML page with some textfields and has to pass the form data to the service. can any one help??

Thankyou

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this

```
 function callWebService{  
        var field= document.getElementById('field').value; 
        //use jquery to convert to json object
        //see comment for more info on this

        var ws = 'http://localhost:8080/WebServicePath/';  
        var url = ws + field;  

        var xmlhttp = null;  
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {  
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();  
        }  
        else if (window.ActiveXObject) {  
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");  
        }  

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {  
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {  
            alert("Success");  
        }  
        else {  
            alert("Failure");  
        }  
        };  
        xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);  
        xmlhttp.send(null);  
    }
```

Comment: you may find these links useful http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/    http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: can u help if the method to be used is POST

Comment: you can check this link for POST http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276226/ajax-xmlhttprequest-post