# passing information through AJAX POST

Tags: php, ajax, forms, post

I am doing something like this, I am passing a variable to a php script via post with AJAX.  It is actually getting inside my php and running my echo, however it is not printing anything out when I print the $_POST array.

```
function ajaxFunction(data){
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}

ajaxRequest.open("POST", "process.php", true);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", data.length);
ajaxRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
        //var data = array();
        //data = document.forms["order_form3"].getElementsByTagName("input");
    }
}

ajaxRequest.send(data);
```

}

Comment: I'm not that good with classic AJAX, however, `readyState == 4` is for after the request is sent successfully, iirc. So, doesn't your `ajaxRequest.send(data);` line should be before the response line?

Comment: I do not see any data sent!

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use a plugin like firebug or even the built in functionalities of Chrome or Firefox to see what has been sent and what has been received in your post request.
The ajax response is not printed somewhere on your screen as you might know it from "normal" http POST requests to a php page. It will be returned as part of your ajaxRequest object and you can fetch it from there to use Javascript to "print" it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to encode your parameters, calling your function does submit your data, however they are unbound to a variable on the other end. I'm not surprised PHP throws your data away.

See here: [AJAX XMLHttpRequest POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276226/ajax-xmlhttprequest-post)