# XMLHttpRequest stalls on send() if I attempt to pass an encoded URL containing an ampersand

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making an Ajax call that sends a URL to a PHP script.  Oftentimes these URLs are complex and contain special characters.  If I *don't* encode the URL before sending, the PHP script works, but the URL's values are interpreted as my values (which is expected).

If I *do* encode a URL that *doesn't* contain special characters, like 'http://google.com' for example, the XMLHttpRequest sends my parameters to my PHP script as expected and everything works fine.

The issue is when I encode a URL that *does* contain special characters, like 'http://google.com?this=that&that=this' -- send() doesn't ever reach my PHP script.  It just hangs indefinitely.  No errors or anything.  I'm stumped.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
function getContent(content, sumbittedUrl){
  var postContent = encodeURIComponent(content);
  var postUrl = encodeURIComponent(submittedUrl);
  var postString = 'content=' + postContent + '&url_get=' + postUrl;

  var httpRequest;

  //create XMLHttpRequest
  .
  .
  .

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = alertContents;
  httpRequest.open('POST', 'php/my_php_script.php', true);
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  httpRequest.send(postString);
}
```

I'm a JavaScript novice so it's possible (likely, even) that I overlooked something that someone with more experience would spot quickly.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Why are you sending a query string in a POST request?

Comment: "It just hangs indefinitely." - How do you know that it hangs?  Is it possible the request is just failing, but not hanging?

Comment: How else am I supposed to format the values that I'd like to pass?  I'm assuming it's hanging on send() since in other situations when requests have failed, I received errors in the console.  In this situation, I can write console.log('before send() is called'); just above the send() method and the statement gets executed.  If I place another console.log('whatever'); beneath send(), it doesn't get executed.

Comment: If your PHP script is expecting a GET request, then use GET and query string.  If it is expecting POST, then use [POST](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4276226/21727).

Comment: Whatever the issue is, it's happening before the PHP script is even called.  Besides, I could be using $_REQUEST to retrieve the incoming values for all you know.  That'd work for GET or POST.  I don't see how my parameters are structured differently from the example you linked except that I'm trying to pass two values instead of one.

Comment: What gets passed in the `content` argument of your function? Can you give an example?

Comment: Sure.  'content' just determines which function to call when it gets to the PHP script.  In all cases, it's just a simple string with no special characters that would make a difference I don't think (e.g. 'summary', 'server_details').

Comment: @greg - I misread your question.  I thought the query string was part of the URL to which you are POSTing.  I didn't realize you were trying to encode a different URL with a query string and pass it as a POST parameter.

Comment: Not a problem.  I appreciate you taking a look anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I found a somewhat anti-climatic solution.  I'm still unsure why encodeURIComponent() doesn't work as expected, but the less destructive encodeURI() is working fine.  encodeURI() doesn't touch these characters: `; , / ? : @ & = + $` so the URL's form stays intact.  Potentially dangerous characters (e.g. `< >`) are still encoded.

The downside is that since ampersands are among the characters that don't get encoded, it means more work server-side to sort out incoming values.

EDIT:

It turns out it was a server-side issue after all.  I was retrieving the values fine the whole time.  The issue was with a cURL request using the aforementioned values.  Don't trust PHP errors/warnings (or lack of them).

Comment: What about "console.log('whatever');" not executing?  What caused that?

Comment: I'm really not sure.  If PHP actually outputs an error, then the readyState and status of the XMLHttpRequest instance is updated.  My PHP script was attempting to send XML-formatted data using cURL and failing (but without errors) and the status and readyState values never changed in JS.