# Why this XMLHttpRequest cause http 406

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, http-status-code-406, oxwall

It is a XMLHttpRequest to get a json form. I tested it on 3 different host:

- localhost: http 200
- my test VPS host: 200
- my shared host godaddy: 406

I have compared the headers again and again. Then I googled and read so many articles the whole day long.. but still can figure out why.. Few suspicious points to me here :

- Request URL:h.t.t.p://example.com/oxwall/base/ajax-loader/component/?cmpClass=PHOTO_CMP_AjaxUpload&r=0.41719201277010143 -> 'oxwall' is my php app, a real directory while 'base' is no a real direcoty.
- XMLHttpRequest is not supported by some configuration of Godaddy?
- json : i see many reported 406 with Json:

My full header that failed:

```
Request URL:http://example.com/oxwall/base/ajax-loader/component/?cmpClass=PHOTO_CMP_AjaxUpload&r=0.41719201277010143
Request Method:POST
Status Code:406 Not Acceptable
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:38
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:.................
Host:example.com
Origin:http://example.com
Referer:http://example.com/oxwall/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.66 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Query String Parametersview sourceview decoded
cmpClass:PHOTO_CMP_AjaxUpload
r:0.41719201277010143
Form Dataview sourceview decoded
params:%5Bnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%2Cnull%5D
Response Headersview source
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Length:404
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:Sat, 09 Aug 2014 09:20:32 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5
Server:Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.10-dev
```

Succesful response in Json:

```
   {"content":"<div class=\"ow_photo_upload_wrap\" id=\"add-new-photo-container\">\n    <div class=\"ow_hidden\">\n        <iframe name=\"iframe_upload\" id=\"iframe_upload\" src=\"about:blank\"><\/iframe>\n        <form id=\"upload-form\" target=\"iframe_upload\" enctype=\"multipart\/form-data\" method=\"post\" action=\"http:\/\/conyeu.me\/photo\/ajax-upload\">\n            <input type=\"file\" name=\"file\" accept=\"image\/jpeg,image\/png,image\/gif\" multiple \/>\n        <\/form>\n        <div id=\"slot-prototype\" class=\"ow_photo_preview_edit\">\n            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"slot\" \/>\n            <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"rotate\" \/>\n            <div class=\"ow_photo_preview_action\">\n                <div class=\"ow_photo_preview_image ow_photo_preview_loading\">\n                    <div class=\"ow_photo_preview_image_filter\"><\/div>\n                <\/div>\n                <div class=\"ow_photo_preview_x\"><\/div>\n                <div class=\"ow_photo_preview_rotate\"><\/div>\n            <\/div>\n            <div class=\"ow_photo_upload_description\" style=\"min-height: 58px\">\n                <textarea class=\"ow_hidden invitation\"><\/textarea>\n            <\/div>\n        <\/div>\n    <\/div>\n\n    <div class=\"ow_photo_dragndrop\">\n        <div id=\"drop-area\" ondragover=\"return false;\"><\/div>\n        <span id=\"drop-area-label\">photo+dnd_support<\/span>\n    <\/div>\n\n    <form id=\"form_79795474\" method=\"post\" action=\"http:\/\/conyeu.me\/photo\/ajax-upload-submit\" name=\"ajax-upload\">\n<input name=\"form_name\" id=\"input_82938081\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"ajax-upload\" \/>\n\n        <div id=\"slot-area\" class=\"ow_photo_preview_block_wrap clearfix\"><\/div>\n\n        <div id=\"photo-album-form\" class=\"ow_photo_upload_bottom clearfix\">\n            <div id=\"photo-album-list\" class=\"ow_left\">\n                <div class=\"ow_suggest_field ow_smallmargin\">\n                    <input name=\"album\" id=\"input_48713404\" type=\"text\" class=\"ow_dropdown_btn ow_inputready ow_cursor_pointer\" autocomplete=\"off\" readonly=\"readonly\" value=\"Ch\u1ecdn album c\u00f3 s\u1eb5n ho\u1eb7c t\u1ea1o album m\u1edbi\" \/>\n                    <div class=\"ow_dropdown_list_wrap\">\n                        <ul class=\"ow_dropdown_list\">\n                            <li>T\u1ea1o Album m\u1edbi<span class=\"ow_add_item\"><\/span><\/li>\n                                                    <\/ul>\n                    <\/div>\n                    <div class=\"ow_dropdown_arrow_down upload_photo_spinner\"><\/div>\n                    <span id=\"input_53937208_error\" style=\"display:none;\" class=\"error\"><\/span>\n                <\/div>\n                <div class=\"new-album\" style=\"display: none\">\n                    <input name=\"album-name\" id=\"input_53937208\" type=\"text\" class=\"ow_smallmargin invitation\" value=\"T\u00ean album\" \/>\n                    <textarea name=\"description\" id=\"input_87690768\" class=\"invitation\">Ch\u1ecdn album hi\u1ec7n c\u00f3 ho\u1eb7c t\u1ea1o m\u1ed9t h\u00ecnh m\u1edbi<\/textarea>\n                <\/div>\n            <\/div>\n            <div class=\"ow_photo_upload_submit ow_right\">\n                <span class=\"ow_button\">\n                    <span class=\" ow_ic_submit ow_positive\">\n                        <span class=\"ow_button\"><span class=\" ow_ic_submit ow_positive\"><input type=\"submit\"  value=\"Submit\" id=\"input_95606675\" class=\"ow_ic_submit ow_positive\"name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\"   \/><\/span><\/span>\n                    <\/span>\n                <\/span>\n            <\/div>\n        <\/div>\n    \n<\/form>\n<\/div>","beforeIncludes":";window.ajaxPhotoUploadParams = {};\n                Object.defineProperties(ajaxPhotoUploadParams, {\n                    actionUrl: {\n                        value: \"http:\\\/\\\/conyeu.me\\\/photo\\\/ajax-upload\",\n                        writable: false,\n                        enumerable: true\n                    },\n                    maxFileSize: {\n                        value: 8388608,\n                        writable: false,\n                        enumerable: true\n                    },\n                    deleteAction: {\n                        value: \"http:\\\/\\\/conyeu.me\\\/photo\\\/ajax-upload-delete\",\n                        writable: false,\n                        enumerable: true\n                    }\n                });\n","scriptFiles":["http:\/\/conyeu.me\/ow_static\/plugins\/photo\/js\/jQueryRotate.min.js","http:\/\/conyeu.me\/ow_static\/plugins\/photo\/js\/codemirror.min.js","http:\/\/conyeu.me\/ow_static\/plugins\/photo\/js\/upload.js"],"onloadScript":"OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'not_all_photos_uploaded', \"Some photos were not uploaded because of excessive size or wrong format\");OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'size_limit', \"K\\u00edch t\\u1eadp tin h\\u00ecnh \\u1ea3nh kh\\u00f4ng th\\u1ec3 l\\u1edbn h\\u01a1n <b>{$size}<\\\/b>Mb\");OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'type_error', \"T\\u1ec7p kh\\u00f4ng h\\u1ee3p l\\u1ec7: {$name}\");OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'dnd_support', \"photo+dnd_support\");OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'dnd_not_support', \"photo+dnd_not_support\");OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'drop_here', \"photo+drop_here\");OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'please_wait', \"Xin h\\u00e3y \\u0111\\u1ee3i trong khi c\\u00e1c \\u1ea3nh tr\\u01b0\\u1edbc \\u0111ang t\\u1ea3i l\\u00ean\");OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'create_album', \"T\\u1ea1o Album m\\u1edbi\");OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'album_name', \"T\\u00ean album\");OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'album_desc', \"Ch\\u1ecdn album hi\\u1ec7n c\\u00f3 ho\\u1eb7c t\\u1ea1o m\\u1ed9t h\\u00ecnh m\\u1edbi\");OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'describe_photo', \"Describe this photo\");OW.registerLanguageKey('photo', 'photo_upload_error', \"Photo upload error\"); var form = new OwForm({\"id\":\"form_79795474\",\"name\":\"ajax-upload\",\"reset\":false,\"ajax\":true,\"ajaxDataType\":\"json\",\"validateErrorMessage\":\"H\\u00e3y \\u0111i\\u1ec1n v\\u00e0o m\\u1eabu \\u0111\\u00fang c\\u00e1ch\"});window.owForms[form.name] = form;\n\t\t\t\nvar formElement = new OwFormElement(\"input_82938081\", \"form_name\");\nform.addElement(formElement);\nvar formElement = new OwTextField(\"input_53937208\", \"album-name\", false);formElement.addValidator({\n        \tvalidate : function( value ){\n                if(  $.isArray(value) ){ if(value.length == 0  ) throw \"B\\u1eaft bu\\u1ed9c\"; return;}\n                else if( !value || $.trim(value).length == 0 ){ throw \"B\\u1eaft bu\\u1ed9c\"; }\n        },\n        \tgetErrorMessage : function(){ return \"B\\u1eaft bu\\u1ed9c\" }\n        });formElement.addValidator({\n            validate : function( value )\n            {\n                if ( null && null.trim().toLowerCase() == \"B\\u1ea3ng tin \\u1ea3nh\".toString().trim().toLowerCase() )\n                {\n                    return true;\n                }\n                    \n                if ( value.toString().trim().toLowerCase() == \"B\\u1ea3ng tin \\u1ea3nh\".toString().trim().toLowerCase() )\n                {\n                    throw \"B\u1ea1n kh\u00f4ng th\u1ec3 t\u1ea1o ho\u1eb7c t\u1ea3i \u1ea3nh l\u00ean v\u1edbi t\u00ean n\u00e0y\";\n                }\n            }\n        });\nform.addElement(formElement);\nvar formElement = new OwTextArea(\"input_87690768\", \"description\", false);\nform.addElement(formElement);\nvar formElement = new OwTextField(\"input_48713404\", \"album\", false);formElement.addValidator({\n        \tvalidate : function( value ){\n                if(  $.isArray(value) ){ if(value.length == 0  ) throw \"B\\u1eaft bu\\u1ed9c\"; return;}\n                else if( !value || $.trim(value).length == 0 ){ throw \"B\\u1eaft bu\\u1ed9c\"; }\n        },\n        \tgetErrorMessage : function(){ return \"B\\u1eaft bu\\u1ed9c\" }\n        });\nform.addElement(formElement);\n\n\n\t\t\tif ( form.form ) \n\t\t\t{\n    \t\t\t$(form.form).bind( 'submit', {form:form},\n    \t\t\t\t\tfunction(e){\n    \t\t\t\t\t\treturn e.data.form.submitForm();\n    \t\t\t\t\t}\n    \t\t\t);\n                        }\n                        \n                        OW.trigger('base.onFormReady.' + form.name, [], form);\n                        OW.trigger('base.onFormReady', [form]);\n\t\tform.bind('success', function( data )\n            {\n                if ( data )\n                {\n                    if ( !data.result )\n                    {\n                        if ( data.msg )\n                        {\n                            OW.error(data.msg);\n                        }\n                        else\n                        {\n                            OW.getLanguageText(\"photo\", \"photo_upload_error\");\n                        }\n                    }\n                    else\n                    {\n                        var url = null;\n                        \n                        if ( url )\n                        {\n                            window.location.href = url;\n                        }\n                        else if ( data.url )\n                        {\n                            window.location.href = data.url;\n                        }\n                    }\n                }\n                else\n                {\n                    OW.error(\"Server error\");\n                }\n            });;window.ajaxPhotoUploader.init();","styleSheets":["http:\/\/example.com\/ow_static\/plugins\/photo\/css\/photo_upload.css"]}
```

Please give me some clue what I need to look into.

Comment: Your server logs might provide more information about why the request was deemed bad.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is clientside, so it has nothing to do with your provider.

Comment: If I understand what I've read, you have an `oxwall.php` on the server.  I am not certain enough of this to put it in an answer, but is the GoDaddy shared server configured to run an extensionless php application?

Comment: @BobBrown I think you're on to something here. The fact that it works on the others is because PHP sets the right response content type header as godaddy maybe just returns the php file as text/html as Pham posted is the response.

Comment: Simple test: put a phpinfo.php on the GpDaddy server and try to invoke it as [h[info, without the extension.

Comment: Well?  Did any of this stuff fix it?  If there's a correct answer, please accept it.  If you've figured it out, please post your own answer to help others, and accept it when SO lets you.  This help business really does need to work both ways.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was off the weekend. I am trying your suggestion now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html (look up 406)

In your response you have:

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
```

In your request:

```
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
```

My guess is you have to set Accept. If you're not using jQuery (not tagged with it) then [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4276396/1641941) is how you can do it with vanilla JS:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Accept"
  , "text/html");
```

You should try to open the url in a browser, since you need to post values to it to see if it works correctly you can create a html file with a form method=post action=your godaddy site.