# How do I change GET method to POST method using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I changed the GET methods into POST in php and ajax files but the logical error here is that every time I add a student into the database it doesn't work. I can't really figure out the problem because I'm new to AJAX.

Here's my code:

php file for adding

```
<?php
//I changed to POST
$q1=$_POST["q1"];
$q2=$_POST["q2"];
$q3=$_POST["q3"];

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db("stud", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO stud_info(IDno, LName, FName) VALUES ('$q1', '$q2', '$q3')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

getting the stud id

```
<?php

$q=$_POST["q"]; //I changed to POST

$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if (!$con)
 {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
 }

mysql_select_db("stud", $con);

$sql="SELECT * FROM stud_info WHERE IDno like '".$q."%'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>IDno</th>
<th>LName</th>
<th>FName</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['IDno'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['LName'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['FName'] . "</td>"; 
 echo "</tr>";
 }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

JavaScript for ajax It doesn't work very well

```
// JavaScript Document
var xmlHttp;

function showStud(id)
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }
    var url="getStud.php";
    url=url+"?q="+id;   
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function addStud(id, ln, fn)
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }
    var url="addStud.php";
    url=url+"?q1="+id+"&q2="+ln+"&q3="+fn;  
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function editStud(id, ln, fn)
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }
    var url="editStud.php";
    url=url+"?q1="+id+"&q2="+ln+"&q3="+fn;
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function deleteStud(id)
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null)
    {
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }
    var url="deleteStud.php";
    url=url+"?q="+id;   
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
    xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged() 
{ 
    if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")
    { 
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
    } 
}

function GetXmlHttpObject()
{
    var xmlHttp=null;
    try
    {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        //Internet Explorer
        try
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e)
        {
            xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

Comment: do you mean there is complexity due to $_POST and $_GEt method conflicting?

Comment: I want to change all the GET methods into POST methods and I want to only run the site using the POST methods

Comment: I works we'll using GET method but It doesn't work well using POST method so that is the problem.

Comment: I think the problem here is in the javascript file

Comment: @user3762884 So you're saying that this statement `document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;` is not working, right?

Comment: yeah something like that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX XMLHttpRequest POST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4276226/ajax-xmlhttprequest-post)

Comment: @user3762884, see my answer.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmsft2rtwkl53rc/admin_ajax_problem.zip?dl=0 please take a look at my source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few things I would like to point out. First you are executing the function `stateChanged` here:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
```

and assigning the RESULT of that function (which in this case is `undefined`) to `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange`.

Now, when the readystate changes, `XMLHttpRequest` attempts to call `onreadystatechange` which is now `undefined`, so nothing will happen.

Try this:

```
function stateChanged(){
    return function(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            if (xmlHttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Now, you are still assigning the result of the function to `http.onreadystatechange`, but this time it is a callable function instead of `undefined`.

And second, to POST data like an HTML form, add an HTTP header with `setRequestHeader()`, and specify the data you want to send in the `send()` method, like this:

```
// Example of deleteStud(id) function
var url="deleteStud.php";
xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged();
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.send("q="+id);
```

**Edited:**

For example, your `showStud` function would be like this,

```
function GetXmlHttpObject(){
    // your code
}

function stateChanged(){
    return function(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            if (xmlHttp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            }

        }
    }
}

function showStud(id)
{ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject();
    if (xmlHttp==null){
        alert ("Browser does not support HTTP Request");
        return;
    }
    var url="getStud.php";
    xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged();
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.send("q="+id);
}
```

So change your other functions accordingly.

**Re-edited:**

There are few additional key things you need to know.

**1)** The correct order of calls is:

- `new XMLHttpRequest`
- `xmlHttp.open()`
- `xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = ...`
- `xmlHttp.send()`

In some browsers, calling `.open` clears any event handlers on it. This allows for clean re-use of the same `xmlHttp` object, which is supposedly more memory-efficient (but that really doesn't matter if you code properly to let the GC do its job). So, simply put the `.open` call before the `onreadystatechange` assignment and you should be good to go.

**2)** `onreadystatechange` isn't just fired once. It's fired multiple times, you need to be able to handle that. These are the codes you need to handle:

- 0 UNSENT - *open()has not been called yet*
- 1 OPENED - *send()has not been called yet*
- 2 HEADERS_RECEIVED - *send() has been called, and headers and status are available*
- 3 LOADING Downloading - *responseText holds partial data*
- 4 RESPONSE is ready - *The operation is complete*

Hence your error check should be inside the `xmlHttp.readyState==4` check, like this:

```
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
    if (xmlHttp.status==200){
        // your code
    }

}
```

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmsft2rtwkl53rc/admin_ajax_problem.zip?dl=0 please take a look at the source code

Comment: @user3762884 You didn't incorporate anything I said. Here's your [updated selectStud.js file](http://pastebin.com/CChnaunn).

Comment: I've updated that also. Please re-run your code with this updated javascript file.

Comment: Evertime I click the add button nothing happens

Comment: @user3762884 I've corrected your code wherever necessary. I've also corrected my answer(*because stateChange function was not called properly*) and added few additional key points. Please read the my answer carefully. [Here's your working code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mqgkb8yp70evw1y/AAAC3L90Il-DzsnPDXuitOqja?dl=0). Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You changed your requests to post - but it seems that you didn't change the placement of your paramters. You still attach them to your url:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged;
xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

You send "null" in the request body.

You will need to send the paramters in the body to make it work as expected by you. Refer to this: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp for further information.

Edit: Small (non-tested) Example:

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.send("q=test?data=asd?moredata=das");
```

Update: Since you attached the dropbox folder / content I tried it.

You are still missing the essential function seRequestHeader as listed above. After adding this i am able to read the POST data.

Example for your code:

```
xmlHttp.open("POST","getStud.php",true);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.send("q="+id);
```

IMPORTANT: The seRequestHeader function needs to be called AFTER the open function and BEFORE the send function.

[image: Endpoint dumps the POST variable and displays content as proof that it works]

Endpoint dumps the POST variable and displays content as proof that it works

Comment: I got an error in getting the stud_id `$q=$_POST["q"];`. Undefined index: q

Comment: That just means that you actually do not receive the data. In general you would wrap your php code in something like if(isset($_POST['p')) { $p=$_POST['p']; }  However that won't fix the error it self. please post the code you use in the send function

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmsft2rtwkl53rc/admin_ajax_problem.zip?dl=0 here's my full source code I'm stuck because of the AJAX stuff

Comment: Not sure if you are still looking for the answer - I updated my response using an example out of your code. Please add the setRequestHeader function.

Answer (score 1):

POST method via JS XMLHttpRequest compared to GET is a bit different.

Just a quick untested example:

GET

```
url=url+"?q1="+id+"&q2="+ln+"&q3="+fn;  
xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlHttp.send();
```

POST

```
url=url;  // stays the same
xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlHttp.send(q1="+id+"&q2="+ln+"&q3="+fn); // params go into .send()
```

**You can find working examples at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)**

**Based on your source**

- addStud function is missing xmlHttp.setRequestHeader
- and xmlHttp.send string is missing & connecting parameters

like so:

```
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlHttp.send("q1="+id+"&q2="+ln+"&q3="+fn);
```

Comment: I got an error in getting the stud_id $q=$_POST["q"]; in the php file

Comment: @user3762884 you are going to have to be a bit more specific. What kind of error ?

Comment: Undefined index: q in the  $q=$_POST["q"]; in the php file

Comment: @user3762884, The error is because you are not adding an HTTP header with `setRequestHeader()`. To POST data like an HTML form, you need to add an HTTP header with `setRequestHeader()`. And even if this works, you won't be able to display anything using `stateChanged` function. I've explained the reason in my answer.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmsft2rtwkl53rc/admin_ajax_problem.zip?dl=0 please take a look at the source code

Comment: user3762884 check my updated answer _(Based on your source)_ segment above. But also @rajdeep-paul was also pointing you in the right direction all along.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined index: q in the $q=$_POST["q"]; in the php file

Maybe because you are using q1 in your php file while on the javascript file you are using q only or vice versa. Make it the same and it should work fine.

And don't forget to add this before xmlHttp.send :

**xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");**