# How can I pass data from client to server use raw AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hello  I have already search but they often use jquery ajax to pass data from js to PHP(server-side).  but for my project it has a bunch of pure js code so I should use raw AJAX to pass data.

For example, if I want to send a variable "Imgname" that value = 13   and want to echo in php page.

this is my try

```
<script>
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200) {
                alert('send to server successfully');
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "test2.php", true);
        xmlhttp.send("Imgname=13");
    }
</script>
```

in test2.php

```
<?php
$temp = $_POST['Imgname'];
echo $temp;   /////output should be 13
?>
```

but error Undefined index: Imgname in C:\xampp\htdocs\test2.php on line 2

Comment: Try `xmlhttp.send({Imgname: 13});`

Comment: @FrankerZ That won't work. The argument to `send()` has to be a string or FormData. You're thinking of `$.ajax()`, which will convert an object to an encoded string.

Comment: @Barmar I pulled it from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

Comment: Something's wrong there. The **Syntax** section doesn't show a syntax like `send(Object data)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you're sending the correct content-type:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Comment: That's the default, you don't need to do it explicitly.

Comment: Not according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4276396/4875631) @Barmar

Comment: It is according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest

Comment: I take it back, the default is text/plain if you don't set the header.

Answer (score 2):

Try sending the header:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "test2.php";
var params = "Imgname=13";
http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
  if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    alert(http.responseText);
  }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in the console in your browser?

Comment: Yes that alert. but in test2.php page (other page) it cannot echo $_POST['Imgname'];

Comment: Where is it that you are asking if you need a submit button?  If you are loading my x.html, it submits automatically and just displays the **die('<pre>'.print_r($_POST, 1));** to prove that **Imgname** is truly being sent by the snippet above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127237/discussion-between-webjuju-and-tuchawat).