# AJAX changes content of the string being sent

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

This is driving me crazy!

I have something like this in JS:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/note.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
console.log(" >>>> " + note  + " " + noteHTML);
xmlhttp.send("what=edit&note=" + note + "&noteHTML=" + noteHTML + "&noteIdx=" + noteIdx);
```

Output in console:

```
 >>>> C++ C++
```

This code sends most of the text correctly through, aka in `note.php` I get the same content than the content on the JS side, but for whatever reasons it does something very strange to the string `C++`. When `note` or `noteHTML` which are strings are set to `C++` then what arrives on the PHP side (in `note.php`) is `C` and not `C++`!! This doesn't make ANY sense to me. Maybe there is something wrong with the encoding I chose. I tried `html` and `plain/text` but for whatever reason I don't even get anything at all on the php side so I gave up with looking into this direction any further. Any idea why?

```
else if ($_POST['what'] == "edit")
{
    printArray($_POST);
}
```

Output in browser:

```
what => edit note => C noteHTML => C noteIdx => 17no
```

**WHY?**

Comment: `+` is a special symbol. And you need to use `encodeURI`

Comment: But isn't that supposed to be taken care of by the encoding itself?

Comment: `+` repesents spaces in a url, so `?abc=a+b+c` is in `$_GET` a field `abc` with the content `a b c`.

Comment: You are sending a `post` why not sending the data as post parameters too?

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions: can you explain please? What do you mean by sending the data as post parameters? PS: I tried `encodeURI(noteHTML)` and it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4276396/4916265  `abc=encodeURIComponent('a+b+c');`

Comment: Ok that one worked maybe you can make that an answer and I accept it? More points to get? ) Thx

Comment: To whoever down voted that, not cool and no reason. This is a valid question and can help many people in the future. And I searched before asking. Couldn't find any help on that precise question/problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change it like this (use `encodeURIComponent()` on each element):

```
xmlhttp.open("POST", "/note.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
console.log(" >>>> " + note  + " " + noteHTML);
xmlhttp.send("what=edit&note=" + encodeURIComponent(note) + "&noteHTML=" + encodeURIComponent(noteHTML) + "&noteIdx=" + encodeURIComponent(noteIdx));
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4276396/4916265